# Что сделал мальчик с воздушным шариком?

Tags: одним-словом

Я тут составляю задачу для студентов. Она звучит примерно так:

> В ряд расположены N воздушных шариков разных цветов. Мальчик проходится по последовательности шариков и, как только видит два соседних шарика одинакового цвета, он их...

Дальше мысль обрывается :)

Можно сказать, что он их лопает? Может, взрывает? Помогите найти слово. Спасибо!

Comment: @Anixx: Протыкает конкретизирует способ "лопания". Я хочу слово, ориентирующееся на результат, а не на метод

Comment: Уничтожает. От них избавляется.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно.

Когда шарик делает это сам - он лопается. Это 100%.

Когда мы ему помогаем - мы его лопаем. Причем именно иголкой или типа того. Сдуть шарик - значит сделать это аккуратно.

Кстати есть способ проткнуть шарик так, чтобы он не лопнул. Так что "протыкать" тоже не подходит.

Comment: А теперь подумай, как будет звучать "мальчик лопнул".

Comment: Замечательно будет звучать. Мальчик лопнул = мальчик слишком много кушал и лопнул. Мальчик лопнул шарик = мальчик взял шарик и лопнул его. Дело в том, что "лопнул" звучит одинаково как возвратный залог и как действительный. Ведь никто не говорит "лопнулся".

Comment: Мальчик слишком много слопал и лопнул.

Comment: "Мальчик лопает шарики" звучит так, как будто он их ест (ср. "лопать пельмени"). Студенты будут смеяться.

Comment: @Artemix - ну что поделать, есть такие случаи когда без контекста не понятно о чём речь. "Дайте-ка мне ручку, сударыня".

Answer (score 3):

May be you need grotesque action, it's more fun :)

Уничтожает, ликвидирует, устраняет, аннигилирует, дематериализует.

Comment: Сжигает, прожигает (лазером), простреливает, разрубает, срезает.

Answer (score 2):

Лопать(св. слопать) также означает есть/кушать и к этой задаче не очень подходит.
Может быть хлопает? хлопнуть шарик. хлопо́к - как раз звук лопающегося шарика.
ещё варианты: убирает, протыкает, прокалывает, сдувает.

Comment: то, что у лопает есть омоним ничего не значит

Answer (score 2):

Может быть эти шарики надуты гелием?  Мальчик их отвязывает - они улетают.

Comment: You're being a smartass, aren't you? :)

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan I don't see how this is a bad idea.  Не обязательно говорить, чем они надуты.  Просто шарики привязаны в ряд.  Мальчик их отвязывает - и они улетают.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan Maybe just a little. :)  But this is a good solution to your problem. The boy does not have to pop the balloons. He needs to remove them somehow, and this is as good a way as any.

Answer (score 1):

Протыкает! И лопает - так тоже говорят.